# Can I add class methods and instance methods from the same module?

Tags: ruby

Newbie question:

I know how include and extend work, what I am wondering is if there is a way to get both class and instance methods from a single module?

This is how I do it with two modules:

```
module InstanceMethods
    def mod1
        "mod1"
    end
end

module ClassMethods
    def mod2
        "mod2"
    end
end

class Testing
    include InstanceMethods
    extend ClassMethods 
end

t = Testing.new
puts t.mod1
puts Testing::mod2
```

Thanks for taking your time ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a common idiom for that. It makes use of `included` object model hook. This hook gets invoked every time when a module is included to a module/class

```
module MyExtensions
  def self.included(base)
    # base is our target class. Invoke `extend` on it and pass nested module with class methods.
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def mod1
    "mod1"
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def mod2
      "mod2"
    end
  end
end

class Testing
  include MyExtensions
end

t = Testing.new
puts t.mod1
puts Testing::mod2
# >> mod1
# >> mod2
```

I personally like to group instance method to a nested module as well. But this is less accepted practice, as far as I know.

```
module MyExtensions
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.include(InstanceMethods)

    # or this, if you have an old ruby and the line above doesn't work
    # base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def mod1
      "mod1"
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def mod2
      "mod2"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out to me. Clear an descriptive info. Thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: See my answer for a rather neat simplification of this. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
module Foo
 def self.included(m)
   def m.show1
     p "hi"
   end
 end

 def show2
   p "hello"

 end
end

class Bar
 include Foo
end

Bar.new.show2 #=> "hello"
Bar.show1 #=> "hi"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Sergio got the accepted answer as he was first.

Comment: Cool, I like this one

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's exactly as simple as you would expect, due to the genius of ruby:

```
module Methods
    def mod
        "mod"
    end
end

class Testing
    include Methods # will add mod as an instance method
    extend Methods # will add mod as a class method
end

t = Testing.new
puts t.mod
puts Testing::mod
```

Or, you could do:

```
module Methods
    def mod1
        "mod1"
    end

    def mod2
        "mod2"
    end
end

class Testing
    include Methods # will add both mod1 and mod2 as instance methods
    extend Methods # will add both mod1 and mod2 as class methods
end

t = Testing.new
puts t.mod1
puts Testing::mod2
# But then you'd also get
puts t.mod2
puts Testing::mod1
```

Comment: And if you need a hook like `self.included`, then you can also use `self.extended`. See https://www.sitepoint.com/hitchhikers-guide-to-metaprogramming-classmodule-hooks/

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. :) Imagine a module/concern that carries two intended sets of methods: one to become instance methods, and the other - class [instance] methods. The question was: how to add both (distinct!) sets of methods from the same module.

Comment: I do realize that's one way to interpret it. But tbh, the question wasn't that clear about a need for two distinct methods sets (even though his existing example code necessitated it). The beauty of it is that a module can be agnostic as to how it is used. You don't have to anticipate how the methods in the module will be used. However, if you had multiple methods in the module, and did both an include and an extend then you'd have all the methods available as both instance and class methods (non-distinct).

Comment: The two distinct method sets assumption - I inferred this from experience. You need this more often than adding the same methods as instance and class methods. :shrug:

Comment: Ok, that's fair. I came to this question since I needed the same method as an instance and a class method. So I guess this is a case of YMMV. :)